# Spark: "Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large." Warning when using manually created aggregation expression

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to build for each of my users a vector containing the average number of records per hour of day. Hence the vector has to have 24 dimensions.

My original DataFrame has `userID` and `hour` columns, andI am starting by doing a `groupBy` and counting the number of record per user per hour as follow:

```
val hourFreqDF = df.groupBy("userID", "hour").agg(count("*") as "hfreq")
```

Now, in order to generate a vector per user I am doing the follow, based on the first suggestion in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33873725/1374804) answer.

```
val hours = (0 to 23 map { n => s"$n" } toArray)

val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
                     .setInputCols(hours)
                     .setOutputCol("hourlyConnections")

val exprs = hours.map(c => avg(when($"hour" === c, $"hfreq").otherwise(lit(0))).alias(c))

val transformed = assembler.transform(hourFreqDF.groupBy($"userID")
                           .agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*))
```

When I run this example, I get the following warning:

```
Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
```

I presume this is because the expression is too long?

My question is: can I safely ignore this warning?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can safely ignore it, if you are not interested in seeing the sql schema logs. Otherwise, you might want to set the property to a higher value, but it might affect the performance of your job:

```
spark.debug.maxToStringFields=100
```

Default value is: `DEFAULT_MAX_TO_STRING_FIELDS = 25`

> The performance overhead of creating and logging strings
>   for wide schemas can be large. To limit the impact, we bound the
>   number of fields to include by default. This can be overridden by
>   setting the 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' conf in SparkEnv.

Taken from: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala#L90

Comment: Can this be set via command line as part of a spark-submit command?

Comment: Where can I find the SparkEnv file. I tried setting that in spark-env.sh but did not help.

Comment: @Arnab I just added ``spark.debug.maxToStringFields=100`` to ``spark-defaults.conf`` and it worked for me. (I'm using spark 2.3.x)

Answer (score 12):

This config, along many others, has been moved to: SQLConf - [sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/363af16c72abe19fc5cc5b5bdf9d8dc34975f2ba/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/internal/SQLConf.scala#L1975)

This can be set either in the config file or via command line in spark, using:

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", 1000)
```

Comment: This would be in Spark 3 I believe