# Spark Scala Cosine Similarity Matrix

Tags: scala, apache-spark

New to `scala` (`pyspark` guy) and trying to calculated cosine similarity between rows (items)

Followed this to create a sample df as an example:

[Spark, Scala, DataFrame: create feature vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866759/spark-scala-dataframe-create-feature-vectors)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.VectorAssembler

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
  (1, "cat1", 1), (1, "cat2", 3), (1, "cat9", 5), (2, "cat4", 6),
  (2, "cat9", 2), (2, "cat10", 1), (3, "cat1", 5), (3, "cat7", 16),
  (3, "cat8", 2))).toDF("userID", "category", "frequency")

// Create a sorted array of categories
val categories = df
  .select($"category")
  .distinct.map(_.getString(0))
  .collect
  .sorted

// Prepare vector assemble
val assembler =  new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(categories)
  .setOutputCol("features")

// Aggregation expressions
val exprs = categories.map(
   c => sum(when($"category" === c, $"frequency").otherwise(lit(0))).alias(c))

val transformed = assembler.transform(
    df.groupBy($"userID").agg(exprs.head, exprs.tail: _*))
  .select($"userID", $"features")

transformed.show
+------+--------------------+
|userID|            features|
+------+--------------------+
|     1|(7,[0,2,6],[1.0,3...|
|     3|(7,[0,4,5],[5.0,1...|
|     2|(7,[1,3,6],[1.0,6...|
+------+--------------------+
```

Trying to follow this post to convert the df into the `IndexedRowMatrix` and having trouble with the `scala` syntax on how to map the `rdd` properly

[Calculate Cosine Similarity Spark Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010126/calculate-cosine-similarity-spark-dataframe)

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val irm = new IndexedRowMatrix(transformed.rdd.map {
  Row(_, v: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector) => 
    org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.fromML(v)
}.zipWithIndex.map { case (v, i) => IndexedRow(i, v) })



<console>:5: error: not a legal formal parameter.
Note: Tuples cannot be directly destructured in method or function parameters.
      Either create a single parameter accepting the Tuple1,
      or consider a pattern matching anonymous function: `{ case (param1, param1) => ... }
  Row(_, v: org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector) =>
     ^
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one, with RowMatrix :

```
def convertDataFrameToRowMatrix(df:DataFrame):RowMatrix = {
    val rows = df.count()
    val cols = df.columns.length
    val rdd:RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = df.rdd.map(
    row => org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.dense(row.getAs[Seq[Double]](1).toArray)
    val row = new IndexedRowMatrix(rdd,rows,cols)
    row
 }
```

And with IndexedRowMatrix :

```
def convertDataFrameToIndexedMatrix(df:DataFrame):IndexedRowMatrix = {
    val rows:Long = df.count()
    val cols = df.columns.length
    val rdd = df.rdd.map(
    row => IndexedRow(rows, org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors.dense(row.getAs[Seq[Double]](1).toArray)))
    val row = new IndexedRowMatrix(rdd,rows,cols)
    row
 }
```

If you want to convert an IndexedRowMatrix or RowMatrix to RDD, that's simple:

```scala
def convertIndexedRowMatrixToRDD(irm:IndexedRowMatrix):RDD[IndexedRow]=irm.rows

def convertRowMatrixToRDD(rm:RowMatrix):RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] =rm.rows
```

If you want to convert it to DataFrame, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29383578/how-to-convert-rdd-object-to-dataframe-in-spark).

As an example of running the function:

```scala
val si = Seq((1,2), (3,4)) 
val myrdd:RDD[IndexedRow] = sc.parallelize(si).map(x => new IndexedRow(x._1.asInstanceOf[Long] ,Vectors.dense(x._1, x._2)))
val irm:IndexedRowMatrix = new IndexedRowMatrix(myrdd)
val r = convertIndexedRowMatrixToRDD(sc,irm)
val t = r.foreach(println)
```

Output:

```
IndexedRow(3,[3.0,4.0])
IndexedRow(1,[1.0,2.0])
```

Comment: thank you very much ... do you know how to convert this to an ```rdd``` or a ```dataframe```?

Comment: I updated the answer. I suppose that you mean you want to convert a RowMatrix or IndexedRowMatrix to RDD or DataFrame.

Comment: thank you ... getting close ... however when converting to RDD ```val rdd = convertIndexedRowMatrixToRDD(irm)
rdd.take(1)``` this error occurs ```java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.collection.TraversableOnce``` ... thinking the irm to rdd function needs adjusted

Comment: No, I think the input should be adjusted. I shall update the answer.

Comment: Which Scala and Spark versions do you use ?

Comment: thank you very much ... will try it out ... using 2.4.3 and 2.11.12

Comment: OK. I use Scala 2.12.8 and Spark 2.4.0. I shall try to work on your own data too ... Can you please tell me why the answer was downvoted ?

Comment: not seeing any downvote ... will mark as correct when i get this working ... what is ```Tools_dev```? how do i import that?

Comment: Sorry! It is my local singleton :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198326/discussion-between-catalina-chircu-and-thepurplepython).